# can't make jQuery work (change image on time interval)

Tags: jquery, css, html

I don't get it why jQuery function is not working. I read on the interned how to load jQuery in wordpress, but with no success. Can anyone help me?

What I did so far:
I've put this in header.php inside  tags:

```
<?php wp_enqueue_script("jquery"); ?>

<?php wp_head(); ?>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/wp-includes/js/jquery/slideshow1.js"></script>
```

css styles used for jquery:

```
 #gallery1{
 float:right;
 width:400px; /* Set your image width */
 height:300px; /* Set your image height */
 }
 #gallery1 img{
position:absolute;
z-index:8;  

 }
   #gallery1 img.active{
z-index:10;
  }
 #gallery1 img.last-active{
 z-index:9;
  }
```

html code:

slideshow1.js:

```
function slideSwitch() {
var $active = $('#gallery1 IMG.active');

if ( $active.length == 0 ) $active = $('#gallery1 IMG:last');

var $next =  $active.next().length ? $active.next()
    : $('#gallery1 IMG:first');

$active.addClass('last-active');

$next.css({opacity: 0.0})
    .addClass('active')
    .animate({opacity: 1.0}, 1000, function() {
        $active.removeClass('active last-active');
    });
 }

 $(function() {
 setInterval( "slideSwitch()", 5000 );
 });
```

I read that I need to change $ to something else, like 'jQuery'. I tried that, but with no luck too.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: check source code and see if something is not working.

Comment: fire up firebug console or chrome's dev tools and check for errors.

Comment: Ok I used chrome's dev tools and it showed this error:
"Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object Window] is not a function".
So I suppose I should change $ to something else? Can anyone tell me the right way to change it?..

Comment: I managed to fix that error, using (function ($){
code..
});
But slideshow still doesn't work..

Comment: If wrapping your code in no-conflict wrappers (see Amit's answer below) doesn't fix the problem, then the issue appears to be a jQuery syntax issue, *not* a **WordPress** issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used this approach and it worked:

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
```

// code

```
$j(function() {
```

//code
});

Answer (score 3):

Wrap the code like this to make it [not conflict with other JS](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_wrappers) libraries wordpress  loads.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // code
});
```

OR

```
(function($) {
    // code
})(jQuery);
```